# Localization with maximal ideal

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let **R** be local ring with maximal ideal **P**. Show that every element of **R\P** is invertible. Now let *e* be an element of **R** satisfying $e^2=e$. How can we prove $e \in {0,1}$.

Comment: Thanks to all for these helpful hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another hint: Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $J$ be its Jacobson radical. For any element $a\in J$ , $1-a$ is an invertible.

In you case, $R$ is local ring, so that maximal ideal $P$ is exactly the radical.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\,\  \color{#c00}{0 = e(1\!-\!e)}\in P\,\Rightarrow\, $ *exactly* $\,\overset{\large\quad\,   {\rm else}\ \ 1-e + e\, =\, 1\in P}{{\rm one\ of}\ \,1\!-\!e,\, e\,\in\, P,\,}$ so other is a unit, so $\rm\color{#c00}{cancelling\ it}\ldots$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Local rings have one maximal ideal and non-units belong to some maximal ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose by way of contradiction that $e\notin \{0,1\}$. Then $eR\oplus(1-e)R=R$ splits $R$ into two proper right ideals. But both halves are contained in $M$... how could they add up to $R$ when $M$ is closed under addition?